# Why would you use getUrl('checkout/url') without adding the _secure parameter?

Tags: magento-1.9

As far as I know the function checks whether HTTPS is activated over the backend. Why would you pass the function to go without it then?

Example:

```
$this->getUrl('checkout/cart');
```

Returns `http://localhost/checkout/cart/` whilst

```
 $this->getUrl('checkout/cart', array("_secure"=>true));
```

returns `https://localhost/checkout/cart/`, but only when its active in the backend. You could call app() and check for the value as well, but its just burning calculating time on the server as the function will only return https when it is enabled anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't answer the "why" ... but maybe it's still useful:

If you use `http` for your unsecure base URL and want to force using secure url on particular pages you can also do this in you `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <cms_newsletter>/newsletter</cms_newsletter>
        <sendfriend_product>/sendfriend/product</sendfriend_product>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>
```

Comment: I belive that this "sometimes https, sometimes http" is a relict from earlier times of securing websites where you especially only secured specific pages. SSL has nowadays another standing.

Comment: Yep. This is why i can't answer the "why" question ... all sites i'm involved use SSL everywhere.